# Why is the xTimerPeriodInTicks affecting the code's runtime?

Tags: c++, esp32, freertos, esp-idf

So for a report I'm trying to time the number of cycles it takes to execute a couple seperate functions in a program running on an ESP32, using freeRTOS. The code looks something like this with init_input_generator() being the first function called, here i'm timing onesecwindow.fifo_iir_filter_datapoint():

```
float geninputarray[SAMPLING_RATE]; //stores the values of an artificial signal we can use to test the algorithm
fifo_buffer onesecwindow = fifo_buffer(SAMPLING_RATE);


esp_err_t init_input_generator() {
    dsps_tone_gen_f32(geninputarray, SAMPLING_RATE, 4, 0.04, 0); //10Hz
    TimerHandle_t input_signal_timer =
        xTimerCreate("input_timer", pdMS_TO_TICKS(10), pdTRUE, (void *)0, input_generator_callback);
    xTimerStart(input_signal_timer, 0);
    return ESP_OK;
}

void input_generator_callback(TimerHandle_t xTimer)
{
    xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(
        input_counter,
        "input_generator",
        4096,
        NULL,
        tskIDLE_PRIORITY + 11,
        NULL,
        PRO_CPU_NUM);
}

void input_counter(TimerHandle_t xTimer)
{
    stepcounter = (stepcounter + 1) % SAMPLING_RATE;
    insert_new_data(geninputarray[stepcounter]);
    vTaskDelete(nullptr); // to gracefully end the task as returning is not allowed
}

esp_err_t insert_new_data(float datapoint)
{
    onesecwindow.fifo_write(datapoint); // writes the new datapoint into the onesec window
    unsigned int start_time = dsp_get_cpu_cycle_count();
    onesecwindow.fifo_iir_filter_datapoint();
    unsigned int end_time = dsp_get_cpu_cycle_count();
    printf("%i\n", (end_time-start_time));
}
```

The thing that i'm noticing is that whenever I change the xTimerPeriodInTicks to a larger number, I get significantly longer time results, which just really confuses me and get's in the way of proper timing. Although the function doesn't scale with the SAMPLING_RATE and thus should give quite consistent results for each loop, output in cycles with a 10ms timer period looks something like this (every 5 or 6 "loops" for some reason it's longer):
1567, 630, 607, 624, 591, 619, 649, 1606, 607

with a 40ms timer period I get this as a typical output:
1904, 600, 1894, 616, 1928, 1928, 607, 1897, 628

As such I'm confused by the output, as they use the same freeRTOS taskcreate to run with the same priority on the same core, I don't see why there would be any difference. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something basic/fundamental here so any help would be greatly appreciated.

## Update

So based on the comments by @Tarmo i have restructured to approach to having a recurring task, unfortunately the output still seems to suffer from the same problem. The code now looks like this:

```
#include <esp_dsp.h> //Official ESP-DSP library
float geninputarray[SAMPLING_RATE]; //stores the values of an artificial signal we can use to test the algorithm
fifo_buffer onesecwindow = fifo_buffer(SAMPLING_RATE);


esp_err_t init_input_generator() {
    dsps_tone_gen_f32(geninputarray, SAMPLING_RATE, 4, 0.04, 0); //10Hz
    
    xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(
        input_counter, // the actual function to be called
        "input_generator",
        4096,
        NULL,
        tskIDLE_PRIORITY + 5,
        NULL,
        APP_CPU_NUM);
    return ESP_OK;
}

void input_counter(TimerHandle_t xTimer)
{
    while (true)
    {
        stepcounter = (stepcounter + 1) % SAMPLING_RATE;
        insert_new_data(geninputarray[stepcounter]);
        vTaskDelay(4);
    }
}

esp_err_t insert_new_data(float datapoint)
{
    onesecwindow.fifo_write(datapoint); // writes the new datapoint into the onesec window
    unsigned int start_time = dsp_get_cpu_cycle_count();
    onesecwindow.fifo_iir_filter_datapoint();
    unsigned int end_time = dsp_get_cpu_cycle_count();
    printf("%i\n", (end_time-start_time));
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show how you modify `xTimerPeriodInTicks`. You're using the FreeRTOS timers API to create a timer, which creates of a new task each time it triggers. That's not very stable design - try to run your payload work in the FreeRTOS timer task or defer it to some persistent task which is runs at desired priority.

Comment: @Tarmo Is there still a way to then bind the FreeRTOS timer task to a specific CPU core? That was my main reasoning behind this structure

Comment: Well, there might be a #define somewhere in the FreeRTOS port for ESP IDF which chooses the core for the timer task. By the way - you've chosen PRO core for your task which is by default encumbered with running the real-time WiFi stack. Anyway, are you absolutely certain you need to pin your task on a specific core? In most cases that is premature optimization. For example, the pre-emptive task scheduler is already running at 10 ms interval, so your timeris really running on task scheduler's resolution - causing aliasing, which you see here. Use HW timers with interrupts for better resolution.

Comment: Also, if you need to perform a high-frequency operation in a high-priority task, *do not* create the task from scratch each time from a low-priority task (e.g. the timer task). The new task will only be created after the scheduler has found time to run the creation code in the low priority thread, which is completely useless for accurate timing in addition to wasting time on resource initialization. Create the high priority task during startup and signal work to it using queues or other thread synchronization mechanism.

Comment: @Tarmo So i've restructured the thing a bit (I hope correctly according to your comments) however I still end up with the same variations regardless of the value I put in vTaskDelay(x). I honestly don't care very much about how accurate the timing is or anything. This part of the code is effectively just running a calculation oversome simulated data so super accurate timing is not really relevant, i just wanted a lot of data to output quickly, so a timer at 20ms to prevent aliasing is also fine. Reason for the core binding is because another part of the firmware occupies the other core.

Comment: You are confused that it takes varying time to execute line `onesecwindow.fifo_iir_filter_datapoint();`? Well, most likely FreeRTOS decides to pre-empt your task and run some other task instead (e.g. WiFi stack). This could be caused by your task blocking or executing for too long. It's normal. BTW, you are using a function I'm not familiar with (`dsp_get_cpu_cycle_count`) to measure time intervals. I'd use [standard system time](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/system_time.html#get-current-time) (see end of section for microsecond resolution).

Comment: @Tarmo No the thing is that I understand that there can be some variance in the measured time because the OS runs some other tasks, that is of course always. what I just don't understand is how having a different x value in `vTaskDelay(x)` delay after executing the function `onesecwindow.fifo_iir_filter_datapoint()` results directly in a different value measured _within_ the function itself, as the delay is only after the function was already called.

Comment: @Tarmo `dsp_get_cpu_cycle_count` is part of the DSP library provided by Espressif. I'll try the other timing method you proposed and see what that gives me.

Comment: So your question might boil down to; why does FreeRTOS schedule your task's execution differently depending on the interval that you sleep between two consecutive wakeups? That's a very hard question to answer as it depends on everything else that's running on that system.

Comment: @Tarmo yeah I guess that's exactly it, thanks for all the help in narrowing it down. It's just that without knowing that I don't know how I can get a consistent and meaningful indication of the processing load of a piece of code

Comment: Ah, you're looking to profile the performance of your code? You can't do that with a simple stopwatch on a preemptive OS for the obvious reasons that you've already seen. You have a few options in order of increasing complexity. O1: you can ask the FreeRTOS scheduler how much real time the task with `input_counter()` spent running: [Run Time Statistics](https://www.freertos.org/rtos-run-time-stats.html) O2: you can use the ESP IDF [Performance Monitor](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/perfmon.html) to do custom profiling. O3: gprof and friends.